# nsis delete doesn't work

Tags: file, nsis, delete-file

I am trying to delete files from a directory.

The Delete commands appear to work but the files are not being deleted.

```
    Delete $fn

    IfErrors fail continue

    DetailPrint "Delete failed, file=$fn"
fail:
    MessageBox MB_ICONSTOP "Could not delete $fn"

    Abort
continue:
    DetailPrint "Deleted $fn"
```

I check the log after the run and it lists all files are deleted but when I check the folders, all the files are still there.

Is there any way to get a reason or message text after a delete executes?

Comment: BTW: your usage of `IfErrors fail continue` makes the line that is immediately after the `IfErrors` check unaccessible, as it will either jump to the `fail:` or `continue:` labels.

Answer (score 0):

Could you double check that the path is correct. Things like `InstallDirRegKey` might set $instdir to something other than your expected folder.

Make sure that you have the `RequestExecutionLevel` attribute in your script.

If it still is unable to delete, try running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which file is failing and why...

Comment: Try deleting the files in explorer before trying other solutions, they might be leftover files from compatibility redirection.

Comment: The path is definitely correct; I'm actually trying to delete files from three different directories, none work.  I've set RequestExecutionLevel to admin.  I can delete the files through Windows Explorer.  I installed ProcessMonitor but I'm sorry, it changed too quick for me to see what was going on.

Comment: You can set a filter in process monitor. There are also some tutorial videos on channel9...

Comment: I established that there are no other processes accessing these files.  I re-wrote the routine in Java, using File.delete() statements and called that from the NSIS script.  Works a charm.  I do not understand why the NSIS delete can't do it??

Comment: Which is why process monitor can help, it should display the error in one of the columns...

Comment: Sorry Anders, I didn't use Process Monitor; I can't understand it.  I used a different tool called LockHunter which insisted there were no locks on any of my files.  I can delete them with a Java program called from NSIS but not from NSIS itself.  Just doesn't make sense.